Back4App React query class to fetch file as data or blob instead of URL
I am trying to generate PDF reports in a manner of an Invoice. These PDFs will also contain images.
The content for the PDF will be fetched from back4app cloud server from a class named Rentings.
The generation of the PDFs will happen on the Client side.
What I initially tried to do was to generate the PDF by using the URL of the image that is being returned from the Query response, as showing below, the _url property.

but this didn't work and the PDF had a blank spot where the image should be. I'm not sure why this isn't working.
The workaround I found was to fetch the image from the back4app server by using the _url fetched previously, like this:
return await fetch(imgURL)
    .then(async (r) => {
      return r.blob();
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
};

Doing so, I have access to the image in a BLOB format where I can then do "createObjectURL" so that a copy of the image is created locally and then the image can be included in the PDF upon generation which worked just fine and the PDF was created with the image being included. But this brought another issue, I am randomly getting CORS error from back4app and PDF generation is not working most of the times due to CORS error.

The PDF library I'm using to generate the PDFs is @react-pdf/renderer
At this point I am not sure if there's any other way of doing what i'm trying to achieve without having to use a different PDF library or doing the PDF generation on the server side in back4app's node environment. My initial goal is to achieve this on the client side and not server side.

Just for clarity, you're pulling the content that will appear on the PDF from Back4App and then the image from... another source? Or is the BLOB image also stored in Back4App?

The content for the pdf is generated in code with html elements. The only thing I'm trying to do is also insert in the pdf an img file retrieved from b4a server.
